# Flutter: obscureText, how to stop showing typed characters

Tags: flutter

When typing text into a field with obscureText: true, each typed character is displayed briefly before being converted to a bullet. How do you stop the behavior?

Comment: Do you want to toggle the obscure text on/off with an `eye` icon (or similar) as many other apps do or something else?

Comment: Something else. Although toggling would be helpful because I want to make it impossible for anyone, including the typer, to see what IS being typed. So checking what WAS typed via a toggle would be helpful. 

The default behavior of obscureText is to briefly display the typed character and then convert it to a bullet. This reveals the password one character a time which could lead to shoulder surfing or password disclosure during a screen share/recording session. The default behavior feels like a mobile feature, but Flutter also runs on desktops.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65352.  As of https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/98150, Flutter now should honor the system setting on Android.

Answer (score 5):

This was [fixed](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/56794) on Web/Desktop, but there's no option to do it on Mobile. You can create a custom TextEditingController as suggested in this [comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32889#issuecomment-577465465):

```
class ObscuringTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan({TextStyle style, bool withComposing}) {
    var displayValue = '•' * value.text.length;
    if (!value.composing.isValid || !withComposing) {
      return TextSpan(style: style, text: displayValue);
    }
    final TextStyle composingStyle = style.merge(
      const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
    );
    return TextSpan(
      style: style,
      children: <TextSpan>[
        TextSpan(text: value.composing.textBefore(displayValue)),
        TextSpan(
          style: composingStyle,
          text: value.composing.textInside(displayValue),
        ),
        TextSpan(text: value.composing.textAfter(displayValue)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Remove `obscureText` and use controller:

```
var passwordController = ObscuringTextEditingController();

TextField(
  controller: passwordController,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Sami's answer, if you want the ability to toggle password show and hide using a suffix icon while using ObscuringTextEditingController, you can initialise as follows:

```
var passwordControllerObscure = ObscuringTextEditingController();
var passwordController = TextEditingController();
```

Subsequently, the TextField would look like:

```
TextField(
  controller: _showPassword ? passwordController : passwordControllerObscure,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                _showPassword
                    ? Icons.visibility
                    : Icons.visibility_off,
                color: colors.primary,
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              onPressed: () {
                if(_showPassword) {
                  //switch text between controllers on toggle
                  passwordControllerObscure.text = passwordController.text;
                  //set cursor to the end of the current controller on toggle
                  passwordControllerObscure.selection =
                      TextSelection.collapsed(offset: passwordControllerObscure.text.length);
                } else {
                  passwordController.text = passwordControllerObscure.text;
                  passwordController.selection =
                      TextSelection.collapsed(offset: passwordController.text.length);
                }
                setState(() {
                  _showPassword = !_showPassword;
                });
              },
             ),
           ),
  )
```